# Как узнать количество списков, и количество элементов в каждом из них?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть несколько списков, внутри которых разное количество элементов. Надо узнать сколько списков, и сколько в каждом из них элементов. А так же ограничить вывод элементов в списках по три, то есть при нажатии на специально обученную кнопку выводится ещё три элемента, если они есть. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать с помощью jQuery?

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3"></li>
    <li class="item-4"></li>
    <li class="item-5"></li>
    <li class="item-6"></li>
    <li class="item-7"></li>
    <li class="item-8"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3"></li>
    <li class="item-4"></li>
    <li class="item-5"></li>
    <li class="item-6"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: пример DOM модели хотя бы напишите, через `правку поста`

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: что-нибудь пробовали сами?

Comment: Пока ничего дельного. Пытаюсь как-нибудь обратиться к каждому элементу list, но получается ко всем сразу.

Comment: Приведите html код кнопки и дополню свой ответ

Comment: <a href="#" class="btn">Показать ещё</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую.

1. Получить количество всех списков

   ```
   $('ul.list').length
   ```
2. Получить количество элементов внутри списков

   ```
   $('ul.list').each(function() {
      $(this).find('li').length; // кол-во элементов внутри каждого списка поочередно
   });
   ```
3. Ограничить вывод элементов в списках по три

   ```
   $('ul.list').each(function() {
      $(this).find('li:gt(2)').hide(); // скрыть те элементы, индекс которых больше 2
   });
   ```
4. Если необходимо, то добавить кнопку в списки, где элементов больше 3

   ```
   $('ul.list').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('li').length > 2) {
         $(this).append('<a href="#" class="btn">Показать еще</a>');
      }
   });
   ```
5. Добавить обработчик нажатия кнопок

   ```
   $('a.btn').click(function() {
      var ul = $(this).parent();
      ul.find('li:hidden:lt(3)').show();        // показать еще 3 скрытых
      if (ul.find('li:hidden').length == 0) {   // если больше скрытых нет
         $(this).hide();                        // то скрыть кнопку
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: Привёл пример кнопки <a href="#" class="btn">Показать ещё</a>. Спасибо, я был близок к решению)) не правильно писал this